# Using let with third person

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

> My mother lets/let me go out at night.

Which one is correct? I checked some sources but couldn't find good explanations as some give third person with **s** while some others don't.

Comment: You may have seen the verb in the past tense, which is probably what is confusing. "She let me go out last night" is in the past indefinite tense.

Answer (score 3):

If it's "at night," that's an ongoing situation:  you were allowed out last night, you're being allowed out tonight, and you will be allowed out in the coming nights.  In this case, use the **simple present** to represent that ongoing nature:  "My mother **lets** me go out at night."

If it's a particular night you're talking about, use the tense that fits, e.g., the **past tense** for a previous night:  "My mother **let** me go out last night."

Answer (score 0):

to let = to allow, permit

The verb "to let" acts like any other verb and takes "s".

"My mother" is 3rd person singular, and therefore, "lets" is correct in the present tense, unless the sentence is in the past tense, which will be "let".

"My mother let me go out at night." - This statement can also mean "My mother used to let me go out at night" if it's in the *past indefinite* tense.

Comment: What if it's in the past tense? :p

Comment: Right. Answer edited.